# Linux command for adding a space before a word

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file (file.txt) that contains data something like below.,

```
6weeksagouser1origin/fb-branch1
6weeksagouser2origin/fb-branch2
6weeksagouser3origin/fb-branch3
```

How do I insert space after "ago" & before "origin". It should look something like below.,

```
6weeksago user1 origin/fb-branch1
6weeksago user2 origin/fb-branch2
6weeksago user3 origin/fb-branch3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` for this:

```
sed 's/ago/ago /;s/origin/ origin/' file.txt
```

Comment: very useful for config.toml file stored in a docker as gitlab-runner service in order to add the "tab" indent. Finally understood sed ( :

Answer (score 1):

Another sed:

```
$ sed 's/\(ago\)\(.*\)\(origin\)/\1 \2 \3/' file
```

Output:

```
6weeksago user1 origin/fb-branch1
...
```

In case there is `...agoorigin...` in the file, maybe `...\(.\+\)...` would be better.